# portforward ec2 instance to localhost for rails development

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, tunneling

I'm trying to work with facebooks real-time updates but I'm having trouble giving facebook a callback address that they can use. My dev machine is behind a firewall so I want to use an ec2 instance to forward traffic to the dev machine.

Progress so far:

- App is up and running on localhost:

  ```
  http://0.0.0.0:5000
  ```
- Created Ubuntu 10.11 instance on ec2
- Authorize ports on ec2 instance

  ```
  localhost$ec2-authorize default -p 5000 
  localhost$ec2-authorize default -p 22
  ```
- Configure sshd on ec2

  ```
  localhost$ssh -i ubuntu@ec2_public_dns -i ~/.ssh/ec2_key_pair.pem
  ec2$sudo echo "AllowTcpForwarding yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  ec2$sudo echo "GatewayPorts yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  ec2$sudo /ect/init.d/ssh restart
  ```
- Start ssh tunnel

  ```
  localhost$ssh -R0.0.0.0:5000:localhost:5000 ubuntu@ec2_public_dns -i ~/.ssh/ec2_key_pair.pem
  ```
- Test it in the browser

  ```
  http://ec2_public_dns:5000
  ```

But nothing happens :( The request just times out. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**PROGRESS**

OK, I'm making some progress hitting the web server on my local machine. After I ssh in, I can get the home page from the prompt using curl:

```
localhost$ssh -R0.0.0.0:5000:localhost:5000 ubuntu@ec2_public_dns -i ~/.ssh/ec2_key_pair.pem
ec2$curl localhost:5000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

It even works with the `ec2_public_dns` from the ec2:

```
ec2$curl ec2-23-20-132-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

but, it can't connect from my local development machine:

```
localhost$curl ec2-23-20-132-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Comment: OK, I figured out where I went wrong. When I created the ec2 instance, I chose "quick launch" because I figured I just needed a simple unix that had sshd running on it. The problem is, this creates a separate security group named "quicklaunch-1". So,

This

    localhost$ec2-authorize default -p 5000

Should be this:

    localhost$ec2-authorize quicklaunch-1 -p 5000

Now, when I test from my local machine, I get the web page I was expecting:

    localhost$curl ec2_public_dns:5000
    <html>
    ...
    </html>

Comment: serverfault is being gay and not letting me answer my own question. The comment above is hard to read because there's no formatting in comments. Oh well. If anyone wants karma, just copy my comment to an answer. I'll totally check that for you ;)

Comment: Well constructed question (good detail and diagnosis). Stack Exchange does encourage you to answer your own question - but for users with less than 100 rep, requires at least an [8 hour wait](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186) (it might be longer for SF, but after some time you will be able to answer your question).

Answer (score 0):

@spinlock: you never returned to claim your answer, but access rules struck me as the first possibility anyway. I definitely recommend anybody using EC2 spend a bit of time with the Security Groups stuff at first, it's powerful and really helpful. For sake of anyone googling, spinlock's answer is:

> OK, I figured out where I went wrong. When I created the ec2 instance, I
>   chose "quick launch" because I figured I just needed a simple unix that had 
>   sshd running on it. The problem is, this creates a separate security group 
>   named "quicklaunch-1".

So do this:

```
localhost$ ec2-authorize quicklaunch-1 -p 5000
```